# I have implemented a jsf-flow, but i am not being able to understand why the "jfwid" param is popping up everywhere outside flow. What's the solution?

Tags: jsf, flow-scope

First I have an ApplicationFlow.java where i have defined the flow definition.
Defined node with

```
    @Produces
    @FlowDefinition
    public Flow defineFlow(@FlowBuilderParameter FlowBuilder flowBuilder){
        String flowId = "appealApplicationFlow";
        flowBuilder.id("", flowId);
         flowBuilder.viewNode(flowId,
                        "/someUrl")
                .markAsStartNode();
          ....
          ...
          ...
       flowBuilder.returnNode("nodenameOutsideFlow")
               .fromOutcome("#{applicationFlowBean.returnValue}");

        Flow flow = flowBuilder.getFlow();
        return  flow;
```

in the ApplicationFlowBean.java

```
@Named
@FlowScoped("appealApplicationFlow")
public class ApplicationFlowBean {

    //other business logic

    public String navigateStepFive() {
        return "someUrl + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String navigtePreviewForm() {
        return "someUrl" + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String getReturnValue() {
        return "someUrl outside the flow package" + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }

}
```

I have tried many tuning back and forth..and found no satisfactory ans.

for example if i click on login button from landing page it navigates to login page with a "jfwid" param in the url though login is outside of the flow. This is causing the UTF-8 encoding to break when entered a string other than in English language.